# error on calling string:indexOf

Tags: javascript, indexof

The line `var ndx = url.indexOf( parameter );` causes the code to return without displaying either of the following alerts. The alert showing the url is correct.

```
function setFrameSrc() {
    var url = document.location;
    if (null == url) {
        alert('Javascript Error: Null Object - document.location');
        return;
    }
    alert('URL = ' + url);

    var parameter = '?image=';
    var ndx = url.indexOf(parameter);
    if (ndx < 0) {
        alert('Parameter not found = ' + parameter);
        return;
    }
    alert('Index of ' + parameter + ' = ' + ndx);

    var frame = document.getElementById('pframe');
    if (null == frame) {
        alert('Javascript Error: Null Object - frame');
        return;
    }
    frame.src = url.substring(ndx);
}
```

What is wrong with this code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`document.location`, despite its appearances, is not a string. You want `document.location.href`.

Even better, you could use `document.location.search`, which includes only the part including and after the `?` (and excluding `#` and after which you aren't accounting for).

Answer (score 0):

#### Change:

`var url = document.location;`

#### To (one of the following):

1. `var url = document.location + '';`
   Note: you'll also need to change the `null` comparison to a blank string (`''`)
2. `(url+'').indexOf`

Answer (score 0):

Its working for me:

```
function test(){
var url = location.href;
if ( null == url ) {
    alert( 'Javascript Error: Null Object - document.location' );
return;
}
alert( 'URL = ' + url );


var parameter = '?image=';
var ndx = url.toLowerCase().indexOf( parameter );
alert(ndx);
if ( ndx < 0 ) {
    alert( 'Parameter not found = ' + parameter );
    return;
}
alert( 'Index of ' + parameter + ' = ' + ndx );
}

test();
```

> Change : **document.location** to **location.href**